# Is there a hypothesis test for members of hierarchical clustering clusters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose my data has $N$ observations, and each observation may be classified into one of three factor levels $\{A, B, C\}$.  Using a vector of attributes for each observation, $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}_i$, I run hierarchical clustering and decide to use $K = 2$ clusters.  In counting the factor levels in each cluster, suppose there are

- Cluster 1: ($a_1$ of $A$, $b_1$ of $B$, and $c_1$ of $C$);
- Cluster 2: ($a_2$ of $A$, $b_2$ of $B$, and $c_2$ of $C$),

where $a_1 + a_2 + b_1 + b_2 + c_1 + c_2 = N$.

I want to test if observations classified as $A$ are more likely to be in Cluster 1 than Cluster 2.  Can I use a straightforward proportion or binomial test?  Or do I need to consider the potential randomness of the sample in assigning the cluster memberships?

Comment: is the clustering method informed of the factor levels? if no, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @carlo No, the factor levels are not in the vector $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}_i$.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't. and, to be fair, to be totally sure of the answer one should know what's the purpose of this whole work. but a binomial test seems like a reasonable tool for the setting (it wouldn't be if the factor was included in the $\{x_i\}$ dataset).